# First steps with MV3: reading the clipboard and editing the contextMenu

Tags: google-chrome-extension, clipboarddata

In my backkground.js file of my MV2 extension, I get the clipboard text value with

```js
    if(document.getElementById('filteredClipboard_data') == null){
        var ta = document.createElement('textarea');
        ta.id = 'filteredClipboard_data';
        document.body.appendChild(ta);
    }
    ta = document.getElementById('filteredClipboard_data');
    ta.value = '';
    ta.select(); 
    if ( document.execCommand("Paste", null, null)) {
        data =  ta.value;
    } else {
        log("paste failed");
    
    }
    ta.value = '';
    return data;
```

It's my understanding that this won't work with a service worker script. Correct ?
I would also know if manupulating the context menu from the service worker is possible :

```
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: menu.title,
    id: menu.fcb_context,
    contexts: menu.context,
    });
```

Is that possible in a service worker script  ?

Thanks

François

Comment: In Chrome 109+ you can create an [offscreen](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) document and use document.execCommand inside + [chrome messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) or navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage to send the result back.

Comment: @wOxxOm Why not fetching the clipboard content in the content script and sending it to the service worker ?

Comment: If you have a content script then do it there, naturally.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes but from [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/), it seems that `chrome.contextMenu`API is only available in the service worker script, not in the Content script. Correct ?

Comment: Yes. Different contexts have different capabilities and restrictions.